# Java Array Sorting, it won't stop inputting digits after index is defined

Tags: java, arrays

I'm doing tutorials regarding sorting Arrays from descending through inputting it from scanner. Yet, after I run it, it won't stop letting me input digits. I've already defined the Array index boundaries to [5], it should stop once at Array.length right? Can anyone point out the problem here?

```
public class Main {

    private static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] myIntValues = new int[5];
        printArray(sortIntegers(getIntegers(myIntValues)));
    }

    public static int[] getIntegers(int[] myArray) {
        System.out.println("Input digits: ");
        for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length;i++) {
            myArray[i] = scanner.nextInt();
        }
        scanner.close();
        return myArray;
    }

    public static void printArray(int[] myArray) {
        for(int i = 0; i< myArray.length;i++) {
            System.out.println("Elemtent "+i+" contests " + myArray[i]);
        }
    }

    public static int[] sortIntegers(int[] myArray) {
        int temp;
            for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
                //use a second forloop because it consecutively changes all the digits
                for(int j = 0; j < myArray.length; i++) {
                    if(myArray[j] < myArray[j+1]) {
                        temp = myArray[j];  
                        myArray[j] = myArray[j+1];
                        myArray[j+1] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }
        return myArray;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your second for loop in `sortIntegers` you accidentally increase `i++` instead of `j++`. Therefore `j` will never reach the length of the array and the loop will go forever.

Comment: Hey thanks for pointing that out, I've changed it, but I'm getting a different kind of error, indexOutOfBounds now, but I don't see how it can be out of bounds? I've defined the index element to 5 now.

Comment: In `if(myArray[j] < myArray[j+1])` when j is 4 your program will try and get the value at index 4 + 1 in `myArray` hence the exception since `myArray[5]` is out of bounds. Try instead `if(myArray[j-1] < myArray[j])` or let your for loop go until `j < myArray.length - 1`.

Comment: MarkusAnd, god bless you. Things got so much clearer now.

Comment: You are welcome, just a last tip if you do not want to write you own sorting algorithm you can use Java's [Arrays.sort method](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/arrays-sort-in-java-with-examples/). To sort in descending order: `Arrays.sort(myArray, Collections.reverseOrder());` or Increasing order: `Arrays.sort(myArray);` but please note that you need to change `myArray` to `Integer[]` instead of `int[]`.